# Add images to email operator on airflow

Tags: python, airflow

I am using airflow 1.10. I would like to add images to the email send from the email operator. I saw that I can attach files, and that I can send HTML content on an email, but when I try to add an image in the html , the resulting email shows an error box, not the image.

How can I overcome this?

```
image_mail= EmailOperator(
    task_id="image_mail",
    dag=dag,
    to=['my_email@mail.com' ],  
    subject='image_mail',
    #html_content=  EMAIL_CONTENT,
    html_content="<img src=\"/scripts/img.png\"></img>",
    provide_context=True
)
```

[image]

Comment: Can you base64-encode your image?  https://www.w3docs.com/snippets/html/how-to-display-base64-images-in-html.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example of how you can do it (It works in Airflow 2):

```
image_mail = EmailOperator(
    task_id="image_mail",
    dag=dag,
    to=['my_email@mail.com'],
    subject='image_mail',
    files=['/path/to/file_name.png'],
    # html_content=  EMAIL_CONTENT,
    html_content="<img src='cid:file_name.png'>",
    provide_context=True
)
```

Comment: it works on Airflow 1.10 too, Thanks!